# Inno Setup: Check if OpenDCL is installed, otherwise install it

Tags: inno-setup

I want that my script checks, if OpenDCL is installed. If it isn't, it should install it.

This is the code:

Source:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{7EED6191-0CC5-4D95-B28B-D5AB92F09685}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName=C:\Cobiax\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
UsePreviousAppDir=yes
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
InfoAfterFile=C:\Cobiax\Sorgenti\Cobiax Plan\info.txt
OutputBaseFilename=CobiaxPlan v1.0      
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=admin                                    

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "C:\Cobiax\"

[Files]
Source: C:\Cobiax\Sorgenti\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi; \
    DestDir: C:\Cobiax\Cobiax Plan\; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: /i {app}\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi

[UninstallRun]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: /x {app}\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
```

Thank you very much, Dennis

Ps. Is it possible to hide that splash screen?

[image: windows installer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have different paths to `OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi` in `[Files]` and `[Run]` section. You install the package to a fixed path `C:\Cobiax\Cobiax Plan`, while you run it from a user-defined installation path `{app}`. As the file is temporary, you probably want to install and run it from `{tmp}`.
2. In any case, both paths probably contain a space (`Cobiax Plan` or `Program Files`). So you run

   ```
   msiexec.exe /i C:\Program Files\MyAppName\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi
   ```

   That's wrong. That's why you get the `msiexec` usage screen.

   If the path contains a space, it needs to be enclosed to quotes:

   ```
   msiexec.exe /i "C:\Program Files\MyAppName\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi"
   ```

The correct code would be:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\Cobiax\Sorgenti\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi; DestDir: {tmp}; \
    Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\OpenDCL.Runtime.8.0.1.0.msi"""
```